# Behavior of accept() and TCP packet delivery

Tags: sockets, tcp, port

Java documentation says that a `ServerSocket`, `x`, that is listening on, say, port `5555` returns a new `Socket`, `y`, from its `accept()` method such that:

1. the local port of `y` is set to `5555`; and
2. `x` continues to listen on port `5555` to `accept()` new connections.

I have verified that the above is indeed the case.

However, this wikipedia entry on [Port](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_%28computer_networking%29) has this to say:

> This process is known as *listening* and involves the receipt of a
>   request on the well-known port and **reestablishing** one-to-one
>   server-client communications on **another private** port, so that other
>   clients may also contact the well-known service port.

To me, the above wikipedia excerpt tends to make more sense... since from what I've read and understood about TCP/IP,

1. the destination IP address helps deliver the packet to the right host; and
2. the destination port helps deliver the packet to the right process on the destination host

Thus, the given the documentation and behavior of `accept()` in Java, I'm wondering how could packet delivery be possibly achieved in case of a multithreaded client attempting to talk to a multithreaded server (by opening two communication channels, one in each thread)? In such a case, how would Java (or, the underlying TCP/IP stack) know which packet belongs to which channel when all packets would have the same destination IP address and port values set?

**EDIT**: Please see EJP's response and also Nikolai's comment below. According to them, the above wikipedia claim was wrong. EJP went ahead and fixed the wikipedia entry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The listening socket is special. The kernel delivers to it only those TCP segments that are part of the [three-way handshake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_way_handshake#Connection_establishment), which have explicit flags in the header. Once that completes you have an *established* TCP connection that is identified by a full tuple `(src addr, src port, dst addr, dst port)`.

Thus there's no ambiguity inside the network stack between listening and connected socket bound to the same local port.

It might also help to study the [TCP state diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aTcp_state_diagram_fixed.svg) to get a better mental picture of how all this comes together.

Comment: I wasn't worried about the listening socket vs the connected socket. Rather, I'm worried about the multiple connected sockets existing within the same process.

Comment: @Harry, different source ports -> different sockets.

Comment: Oh, ok, I get it now. Thanks! But, one more thing: why does Java return the same, listening port value on the connected socket's local port when the wikipedia entry says **another private** port?

Comment: Wikipedia is not exactly an authoritative source - it is wrong in this case :)

Comment: Thanks for your prompt and helpful answers, Nikolai. May be, you could help correct wikipedia as I'm really not an expert on these things.

Answer (score 1):

The Wikipedia article is wrong. *Was* wrong: I fixed it. Take another look now. The accepted connection uses the same local port number as the listening port.

Comment: The Internet is a joy and an addiction because of folks like yourselves. Thanks and +1! (I will mention about your fix in my question above.)